# How do I unit test a method which handles parameters based on their type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method called `ProcessMessage(IMessage message, IMessageHandler<IMessage> messageHandler)`. The containing class has a collection of Message handlers: `List<IMessageHandler<IMessage>> messageHandlers`.

I need to pull out a specific Message Handler from my `List<IMessageHandler<IMessage>>` to process any given message correctly.

```
ProcessMessage(message, this.messageHandlers.SingleOrDefault
(
    mh => mh.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetType() == message.GetType()
));
```

My problem occurs when I try to unit test this function. I need to populate my `List<IMessageHandler<IMessage>>` with mocked up message handlers. Unfortunately, GetType() is non-virtual and I get the standard "Invalid setup on a non-virtual member" error from moq. Or a better way to setup my test data?

Is there a better way to architect this so that I don't have to use a non-virtual method (ie: GetType) to do that comparison?

Comment: I think you've got one too many `GetType()` in there, the left side of that comparison is always going to be `typeof(System.Type)`.

Comment: Even if I do, that still leaves two GetType() calls to mock. Which still leaves me with the same issue. Once I can step through the code I'll be able to see what's actually returned at each layer and clean that up.

Answer (score 0):

You should never base your unit test on implementation details, you should test the functionality of your code instead.

The fact that your code is using `GetType()` method is an implementation detail only. What is more important is that your code should be able to find the correct message handler for a provided message.

To test the functionality of your code, you can create a few manual implementation of the `IMessage` and `IMessageHandler<IMessage>` interfaces. A few test cases worth covering:

1. The correct message handler gets invoked
2. There are multiple message handlers for a certain message
3. There are no message handlers for a certain message

Comment: That's problematic at a few levels. Most significantly it means that my ProcessMessage test is now dependent on a lower level method's success. I want to be able to test "ProcessMessage" as a unit, not "ProcessMessage and everything it calls downstream." That's kind of the point of mocking and unit testing vs integration testing. "When downstream method does X, my code should do Y." If I have to fully flesh out multiple versions of the downstream method then I'm no longer testing just this method.

Comment: Generally speaking you are right, you should always isolate all dependencies you don't have control over in order to make your test reliable and fast, however in this case that dependency is the .NET BCL itself. You can always introduce another layer of abstraction in order to improve testability, but in this case you would wrap the `mh.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetType() == message.GetType()` expression, which, let's be honest, wouldn't add much value.